# How to keep user always logged in without infinite session

Tags: security, session, cookies, https

Wondering how this is typically implemented. Examples of always logged in websites are StackOverflow, Facebook, and Twitter. It seems like you'd have to have a background job regenerating the session ID (assuming you store session by ID in a database) before the session expires (say you tell the cookie to expire in 5 minutes). So every 5 minutes every session would be regenerated to keep it logged in while also keeping it secure. But before going down that road I'd like to know if this is how others implement it or if there is a more standard approach.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is how it is done in majority of websites.

A cookie is set with an access token and **limited** life(of course, if the user checks on'Keep me logged in'). If the user comes to visit the site within that timespan, he is logged in and a current session is generated(from the server). And, the cookie timespan is reinitialized to the pre-decided time.

Say for example: I log in to a website example.com and check its check box, to keep me logged in. Now, as soon as I click the login button and and validated by the server, the server generates a session(for current session) and a cookie(for future sessions), with a time limit of say 1 month. Now, If i come back on say 29th day and open example.com, I shall automatically logged in using the token set in the cookie. The cookie will send my info to the server and the server shall generate my current session. Most importantly, the server will reset the cookie to expire after one month.
If, I return to the website after 30 days, then the cookie will either force me to login again.

I hope my input would be of some help to you.